# Go: open ../src/web/views/index.htm: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: html, css, go, filepath

So i am having strange file path issues in Go. Here is what my file structure looks like.

```
C:/ProjectName/
-------------->bin/
-------------->pkg/
-------------->src/web/
---------------------->main.go
---------------------->controllers/Constants.go
---------------------->content/css/index.css
---------------------->views/index.html
```

My go enviroment variables

```
GOBIN=C:\ProjectName\bin
GOPATH=C:\ProjectName
```

In the file `index.html`, i access the css file like so `<link href="/css/index.css"...` but this doesn't work. The `css` file is not found.
Also in the `Constants.go` file i access the `html` file like so `const indexFile string = "../src/web/views/index.htm"` but this also doesn't work.

If i access the `css` file like this `/content/css/index.css` it works, and if i access the `index.html`file like this `"../web/views/index.htm"` it also works.

The problem is that i am on a team, and everybody else's code works in the way that doesn't work on my computer. And every time i make the changes to make it run on my computer, it breaks on every other persons computer.

Any idea on what the problem could be and how to get about fixing it?

Thank you,

EDIT 1: My handlers

```
router := httprouter.New()
router.GET(basic("/", IndexFunc))

func basic(p string, h func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) (string, 
httprouter.Handle) {

    return p, wrapHandler(alice.New(context.ClearHandler).ThenFunc(h))
}

func IndexFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) 
{    
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("../src/web/views/index.htm")
    checkError(err)
    t.Execute(w, nil)
}
```

alice -> https://github.com/justinas/alice
context -> https://github.com/gorilla/context
function `indexFunc` just serves the `index.html` file.

Comment: The location of the html assets shouldn't have any relation to the Go source code.

Answer (score 0):

We need to see the code you are using to host the files to be sure, but usually what I will do to serve a directory is this:

`http.Handle("/content/", http.StripPrefix("/content/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("content"))`

This will:

- Serve all files inside "content" (relative to where you are running app from) at `/content/*`
- Strip ("/content") from the front of all urls before looking up the file in that dir.

I try to put all static files in a common directory to make this easier.

My guess is you are just doing `http.Handle("/", http.Fileserver(http.Dir(""))` or something, which just serves all files at their paths relative to the working dir.

**Edit**:

In go apps, you have to specify the path for each handler. You need to either move the files to match the urls you want, or define multiple url mappings. I would usually recommend handlers in this setup:

1. API handlers under `/api` defined one at a time (`http.HandleFunc("/api/whatever", myHandler)`)
2. All Static content served from `/static/*` from a single directory. (First line in answer above). So `/content/css/style.css` serves `./content/css/style.css`
3. Anything else serves "index.html". `http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){ http.ServeFile(w,r,"path/to/index.html") }`

Comment: "Serve all files inside "content" (relative to where you are running app from) at /content/*"  But if i do this, then every request that comes in will be redirected to the `/content/` folder. But i don't want this. the content folder only contains the `css` and `js` files.

Comment: Also, this does't explain with i can't access the `html` files from the `Constants.go file`. Its even weirder that it works for other people on my team but not me

Comment: I see. Clarified some. If you could post your `http.Handlexxx` lines it would help.

Comment: Just did. I am using a lot of external libraries, like the julian schmidt router.

Comment: Not seeing what handler would be serving anything from /content

Comment: Also, what command are you using to run your app? What is your working dir?

Comment: I just posted the handler. Also, i'm in the `c:/projectname/src/web/` folder. That is where my `main.go` file is located. So i just run `go run main.go` to run the app